# Windows Phone 7 Application Deployment issues in Device

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-phone-7, endpoint

Hi this is first time i am working with my WP7 device and WCF,

I am using WCF services to communicate with centralized database, when i try to run the app in emulator its working perfectly fine, but when i deploy it to device, i am getting following error message

```
  EndPointNotFoundException
  There was no endpoint listening at http://10.11.32.211:88/ABCService/Service.svc
  that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP 
  action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

**My Web.config file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <!-- <client>
      <endpoint address="http://10.11.32.211:88/ABCService/Service.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IABCService"
        contract="ABCServiceReference.IABCService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IABCService" />
    </client> -->
    <bindings>

      <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBinding_ABCService" sendTimeout="00:01:30" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Buffered">

      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
    </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>

      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>

      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  </configuration>
```

**Application Config File**

```
 <configuration>
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IABCService" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://10.11.32.211:88/ABCService/Service.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IABCService"
            contract="ABCServiceReference.IABCService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IABCService" />
    </client>
 </system.serviceModel>
 </configuration>
```

**Inner Exception**

```
"The remote server returned an error: NotFound."
```

### Stack Trace

```
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.OnGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.<InvokeGetResponseCallback>b__8(Object state2)
at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)
at System.Threading.Timer.ring()
```

I connected to My Lan using WIFI

Comment: Is there an innerException? Can you post the details if so?

Comment: The message suggests that the network service cannot be found.  When you run in an emulator, is it possible that VS is starting a debug copy of your service automatically, and this copy of the service is not running when you test on the real device?

Comment: is it possible to delete the debug copy?

Comment: from other computers and even in from windows phone browser also i am able to connect the service

Comment: Does your application advertise that it requires network access? I don't know whether this affects non-published apps, or whether this would have broken the emulator too, but the manifest for a WP7 app typically needs to indicate that the application will access the network.

Comment: this is a simple application which has login from facebook and store the friends details in the database. Facebook Login is working but the WCF is not working on PHONE

Comment: Application requires network access, it is not published yet

Comment: so this application also work in windows 8 mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue with the Local DNS/Router, Resolved it by changing the settings in the Router and DNS

Answer (score 0):

I think that your endpoint IP **10.11.32.211:88** is not public, soy with your phone you can access there